# MVC One to one relationship with codefirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Iam trying to create one to one relationship with my models. But I'm getting following error: " Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'DetayAcıklama_UrunBilgi_Target' in relationship 'DetayAcıklama_UrunBilgi'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'."

My models are like below:

```
public class Urun
    {
        [Key]
        public int UrunID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UrunKodu { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public decimal Fiyat { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DetayBilgi")]
        public int DetayAcıklamaID { get; set; }
        public DetayAcıklama DetayBilgi { get; set; }

    }


public class DetayAcıklama
    {
        [Key]
        public int DetayAcıklamaID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Açıklama")]
        public string AcıklamaTxt { get; set; }

        public decimal Fiyat { get; set; }

        [Required, ForeignKey("UrunBilgi")]
        public int UrunID { get; set; }
        public Urun UrunBilgi { get; set; }
    }
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: First you need to decide which one is the relationship *principal* (being referenced) and *dependent* (referencing). Then remove the FK (`XyzId`) property from the *principal* (they cant have both FK `Id`s). Then decide if you want to use [Shared Primary Key Association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations) (easier and more naturally supported by EF) or [Foreign Key Association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current implementation doesn't say which is dependent table on which table.. for that specify a primary key column as the foreign key:

```
    [Key, ForeignKey("UrunBilgi")]
    public int DetayAcıklamaID { get; set; }
```